# Add New Kernel Configuration Options

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

Is it possible to Add New Kernel Configuration Options? And if it is possible how ?
I dont mean use

> Make menuconfig

but adding option to menuconfig.

Comment: Yes. Start by reading kernel documentation.

Comment: I extended my question

Comment: @SamNa: You may read [Documentation/kbuild/kconfig-language.txt](https://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/kbuild/kconfig-language.txt): it describes format of config files, using which you can easy add your own configuration option. It is unlikely that someone on Stack Overflow will provide complete **manual** for adding options.

Comment: Copy an existing config. The same answer goes for every "how to add a new X to the kernel" :-)